# Java Lambda Expressions and event info

Tags: java, lambda, event-handling, event-listener

I’m 600 pages into a Java text and have run into something confusing.

In the section on Swing programming, it shows three different ways to create an “EventListener” to handle button clicks. First it shows how to use a function in a class that implements `ActionListener`, then how to use a nested class that implements `ActionListener`, and finally how to use a Lambda Expression.

The first two methods use an essentially identical function (comments are mine):

```
…
  button1=new JButton("foobar");             //create a button object
  button1.addActionListener(this);           //add an event handler to it
…
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { //event handler (standalone or in a class)
  if (e.getSource() == button1) {            //check if event source is the button
    //do something
  }
}
```

That’s pretty straightforward; a button is created, and either the button object itself, or a separate class containing a function are passed to `addActionListener` to add an event handler to the button.

The Lambda Expression uses a slightly stripped down function that looks deceptively similar:

```
…
  button1 = new JButton("foobar");                //create a button
  button1.addActionListener(e -> button1Click()); //set button1Click as event handler
…
public void button1Click() {                      //event handler
  //do something
}
```

What confuses me is the lack of event info. In the first two methods, the functions have to check the event source to see if it is the button, but the Lambda Expression just assumes/knows that the event source is the button. How?

Where does it get that? The call to `addActionListener` starts with `button1`, but it is not mentioned anywhere in the Lambda Expression. Also, doesn’t this mean that using a Lambda Expression limits what information is available? There is no reference to `e` in the function, so it would have no way of accessing the functions to find out things like the keys, timestamp, etc.

<sup>(Oh, and why Java calls it an event *listener* instead of a *handler* like almost every other language is beyond me. And they say that Java and JavaScript are similar in name only…)</sup>

Comment: You're adding the lamba to one and only one JButton, similar to passing in an anonymous inner class. When doing this, there's no need to check the button's source. If on the other hand you created a lambda and passed this same single lambda into several buttons, then you'd want to pass the ActionEvent, here e, into the button1Click method:

Comment: `e -> button1Click(e)`. Then the button1Click method would of course require an ActionEvent parameter, and you could call `getSource()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the listener passed in the non-lambda cases is `this`, that is, the object setting up the button. Presumably, that object (some controller or container) might serve as an event listener for multiple buttons, so to has to distinguish which one sent the event. The lambda, on the other hand, is creating a one-off handler instance attached solely to that single button, so there's no ambiguity.

Comment: That’s what I assumed, but I cannot figure out where the pointer (for lack of a better term) to the button object is coming from. With the first method, I can see it being used because of the `this`, but in the lambda (and even the inner class now that I look at it), there is no reference to the button object. I can only assume that this is all happening automatically behind the scenes (which is nice for the GC, but just leads to confusion for things like this).

Comment: @Synetech That's just basic Java; the reference to the *button* comes from `new JButton`. Then you call a method on that button, passing an object that's an event listener. With the lambda, the listener object is only used once; otherwise, it might be reused for multiple buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You mention a "lack of event info" in the lambda expression.  The event info *is* there in the Lambda expression--it's just not being used like it is in the other example.

The expression in this context,

```
e -> button1Click()
```

is shorthand for

```
(ActionEvent e) -> buttonClick()
```

so you can see that `e` is the event info.

On the other hand, if by "lack of event info", you mean "lack of use of the event info", the answer is, you're right, it appears to be wrong. The two approaches are equivalent, so to compare apples to apples, either neither example should check the source, or both should.

Comment: By lack of event info, I mean `e` is only seen in the call to `addEventListener` and is not passed to the function `button1Click` (which takes no arguments), so not only does it not see the event source, it also seems to be unable to access other event information like key presses or timestamps.

Comment: @Synetech, the two approaches are very much alike in what they are capable of.  The lambda could have been written equivalent to the first example, e.g.`(ActionEvent e) -> { if (e.getSource() == button1) {  /*do something*/  }}`.  It does the exact same thing, with the same information, as the first example. Both approaches register the event listener, both handlers have access to the same event passed in, and both have visibility to the same class fields and member functions.  Why that specific example was written differently, ignoring the event data, is another issue.